# CALayer in UIScrollView has a wrong size

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, calayer

I'm trying to zoom `UIImageView` and `UIView`, which are inside the `UIScrollView`, but it doesn't work.

I have an `UIImage and CALayer`, both of them have an equal size (`2048×2155`). These components wrapped into UIImageView (image view) and UIView (canvas) and displayed inside UIScrollView.

The image view and canvas have the same `content scale factor`, which equals 2.0 (UIScreen.main.scale), but the canvas has the wrong size (see picture below).

[image]

CALayer sublayers were built by using `CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath`.

The `UIScrollViewDelegate` looks next:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    canvas
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.scrollView.centerContentView()
}
```

The center content view looks next (method inside custom UIScrollView):

```
func centerContentView() {        
    let boundsSize = bounds.size
    var centerFrame = canvas.frame
    
    if centerFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        centerFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - centerFrame.size.width) / 2.0
    } else {
        centerFrame.origin.x = 0
    }
    
    if centerFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        centerFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - centerFrame.size.height) / 2.0
    } else {
        centerFrame.origin.y = 0
    }
    
    imageView.frame = centerFrame
    canvas.frame = centerFrame
}
```

All my efforts have failed. I tried to transform the CALayer with canvas but to no avail. I will be grateful for any suggestions or help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by using the next lines:

```
let scale = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / imageSize.height
let scaleTransformation = CATransform3DMakeScale(scale, scale, 1)

for layer in layers { 
   layer.transform = scaleTransformation
}
```

where the `imageSize` equals to the `2048×2155` and everything works fine.
Thank you.